# Firestore retrieve information to ReactJS website

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

New to React and I have never used Firebase before so bear with me.

I have achieved what I want to with local json files. I'd like to replace the local json files with Firestore database.

I'd like to go through the data from Firestore and map them in a card like this.

json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "subject1",
        "img": "https://image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "subject2",
        "img": "https://image.jpg"
    },
...
```

```
import SubjectCards from "./SubjectCards";
import subjectsjson from './subjects.json';

<div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 p-5 md:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 min-[1700px]:grid-cols-4 justify-items-center">
                {
                    subjectsjson && subjectsjson.map(subject => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <SubjectCards name={subject.name} img={subject.img} />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                   
                }
                 
            </div>
```

I set up a firestore database through their website. I have a collection `subject-images` with three sub collections. Inside there I would have 12 to 24 subsubcollections. And in there I'd have a collection with 2 fields. Collection called `card` with a string `name` and a string `img`.

I think my setup is stupid. But I'd need to be able to sort through the 3 subcollections and display all the subsubcollections in different cards. So if there is a better way of doing this, please tell me.

I wanted to display the information from this Firestore database in my ReactJs App as cards, but I have no clue how to retrieve the data.

I tried console.log the data but it won't log anything, except an error after a while.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

export default async function RetrieveData() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
      };
      
      // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
    
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "subject-images"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
    return (
        <>{querySnapshot}</>
    )
    
}
```

I know this looks ridiculous, but I have no idea how to do it

Could someone help me to mimick what I did with local json files but now with the Firestore Database?

Comment: You are trying to retrieve docs from a single collection. Try [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to retrieve data from group of collections.

Comment: @RoopaM How do I set up my Firestone then so that it mimics the usage of my json file?

Comment: You may go through this [document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data) once

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, have you filled in the config values with wat is given to you when you create your database?

You are wanting to return the function? I take it as you want to return the data obtained from the query?

Comment: yes i have, for security reasons i removed them from my post.

Comment: and yes you are right, i want it to return the data if that’s the best way to do it.